# Extending continuous functions from $\partial X$ to $X\cup \partial X$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, graph-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Consider a proper geodesic hyperbolic space $X$ (in the sense of Gromov). Let $\partial X$ be its Gromov boundary. Consider a complex-valued continuous function on the boundary $f\colon\partial X\to\mathbb{C}$. Is it possible to extend $f$ to a complex-valued **continuous** function on $X\cup\partial X$?

In particular, I am interested in the case where $X$ is the Cayley graph of a discrete hyperbolic group.

Comment: I don't know anything about the setting, but does the Tietze extension theorem apply here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem

Comment: A possible strategy would be to associate to each point $x\in X$ a probability measure $\mu_x$ on $\partial X$, such that the measure depends continuously on the point and converges to $\delta_\zeta$ when $x$ converges to $\zeta\in\partial X$. I think such construction exist at least in particular cases (e.g. limit of the uniform measure on spheres, or using the critical exponent maybe). Then you extend $f$ by $\int f d\mu_x$.

Comment: @ThomasRot: Thanks for the advice, I didn't think about it. I'll work on it.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: Are you referring to something similar to the Patterson-Sullivan construction? (I'm not really into it, so maybe I'd better deep my knowledge about it. Thanks for reading, thanks for the advice.)

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I had in mind (I have not worked with this myself, I just remembered that Besson-Courtois-Gallot have used these measure to prove their celebrated rigidity result). The reference     Pacific J. Math.
    Volume 159, Number 2 (1993), 241-270 by Coornaert seems relevant by I have trouble retrieving it to check.

Comment: ThomasRot is right, $X \cup \partial X$ is a compact Hausdorff space so the Tietze extension theorem applies to your situation, if you only require continuity. What BenoîtKloeckner is refering to also works but it is much more powerful.

Comment: I checked ThomasRot's advice, as NWMT says, Tietze Theorem seems to work! I actually need only the continuity of the extended function (which, actually, takes values in $\mathbb{C}$, but this seems not problematic). Thanks to everyone for the help!